# I can't run electron using node.js

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to run electron using node.js but it has a problem 
Please look at my code.

**app.js**

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window 
will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
// Create the browser window.
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

// and load the index.html of the app.
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'Page1.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}))

// Open the DevTools.
// mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

// Emitted when the window is closed.
mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
})
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
// On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
// to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
}
})

app.on('activate', function () {
// On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
// dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
}
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

**Page1.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.6.0/annyang.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="cardbox" class="ui blue fluid card">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-console-app1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "NodejsConsoleApp1",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "user"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "app": "^0.1.0",
    "electron": "^1.6.10",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.10"
  }
}
```

I'm going to go into this project, entered "npm install && npm start"on node cmd
but it indicates an error. 
npm ERR! windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\node.js\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\node.js\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script : start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\My project route\npm-debug.log
please help me

Comment: Did you have a look at the npm-debug.log ? Does it give something extra ? 
Btw, are you sure you need the npm-package app ?

Answer (score 2):

`npm start` is shorthand for `npm run start`.

In your package.json there is no `script` option specified nor is there a `start` script. An example package.json would be:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-console-app1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "NodejsConsoleApp1",
  "main": "app.js",
  "script": {
    "start": "echo 'Hello World!'"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "user"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "app": "^0.1.0",
    "electron": "^1.6.10",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.10"
  }
}
```

You will need to update the example to run the correct `start` script, of course.

Answer (score 2):

In your package.json add a script for running electron

```
"script": {
  "start": "electron ."
}
```